GradleBuildFailed Error In Unity Android Build
I hope you have a good time.
I have been facing the output problem in Unity for Android for almost 1 year.
This problem tells only one thing that the "gradle build failed. see the console for details".
I live in Iran, so I am banned from these platforms, but using DNS and even VPN, this problem is displayed.
I even deleted my previous Unity and installed a newer version (Unity LTS 2022.3.26f1 ), but it didn't matter, I will explain the errors to you.
I tried many different methods with different dns and vpn, but it didn't work.
I remember that once this problem was fixed for me, but after uninstalling and installing it, it returned to the previous state.
These are console errors.
Link

If anyone knows the problem, I will be happy to help.
